# Dynamically Change Page <Head> In Angular2

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular, angular2-routing

In AngularJS 1 we simply add ng-app at top of the HTML tag and bind services to change metadata on the fly.

But in Angular2 the quickstart app in official site made index.html completely static (css, meta, ...), only left app tag to bind with bootstrap()

Now how we can do when we want to build many panel with different style and js plugins, meta keyword...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update**

There is now also the `Meta` service that allows to modify meta tags

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/Meta-class.html

**original**

There is currently no support built in in Angular. There is an open issue though for (almost) full support of meta tags and other stuff in `<head>`.

Currently there is only built-in support for the `<title>` tag using the [Title](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/Title-class.html) service.

```
constructor(private title:Title) {
}

updateTitle(title:string) {
  this.title.setTitle(title);
  console.log(this.title.getTitle());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just released [@ngx-meta/core](https://github.com/nglibs/meta) plugin, using that you can add meta information inside the data property of routes:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path : 'home',
    component : HomeComponent,
    data : {
      meta : {
        title : 'Sweet home',
        description : 'Home, home sweet home... and what?',
      }
    }
  },
  {
    path : 'duck',
    component : DuckComponent,
    data : {
      meta : {
        title : 'Rubber duckie',
        description : 'Have you seen my rubber duckie?',
      }
    }
  },
  {
    path : 'toothpaste',
    component : ToothpasteComponent,
    data : {
      meta : {
        title : 'Toothpaste',
        override : true, // prevents appending/prepending the application name to the title attribute
        description : 'Eating toothpaste is considered to be too healthy!',
      }
    }
  }
  ...
];
```

If you want to override values supplied at the route configuration, it's possible to set meta information programmatically - just in the component class:

```
...
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MetaService } from '@ngx-meta/core';
...

@Component({
  ...
})
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
  constructor(private metaService: MetaService) { }
  ...
  ngOnInit() {
    this.item = //HTTP GET for "item" in the repository
    this.metaService.setTitle(`Page for ${this.item.name}`);
    this.metaService.setTag('og:image', this.product.imageUrl);
  }
}
```

You can find detailed instructions at [@ngx-meta/core](https://github.com/nglibs/meta) github repository. Also, source files might be helpful to introduce a custom logic.

Comment: @Brian no problem, simply subscribe to the route data (resolved data) at `ngOnInit` and call the meta service at this level (within the subscription). It should work without a problem.